# Ubuntu htaccess issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, web-config

I've been looking through the stackoverflow website and am unable to find the answer to my question.

When apache2 was installed it has been left with defaults and the webroot is /var/www/ however if i create a new webspace called /var/www/test/ if i input a .htaccess file it doesn't work. I have tried to add to the default.conf file and then reload the file but it still doesn't work. can anybody advise?

my apache config file is as below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

can anyone offer any advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have this line in your Apache config file (`/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` by default)?

```
AllowOverride None
```

If so, change it to include the features you need in your `.htaccess` file (see the [`AllowOverride` documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride)).

```
AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo ...
```

---

There may also be problems with your `.htaccess` files.  For example, you have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
```

Is `mod_rewrite` actually enabled?  If not, you'll need to do that.

You said you also tried:

```
Redirect /index.html mynewwebsite.com/foldername
```

This will only do anything if you actually go to `/index.html` in a browser.

Comment: thats what i don't understand that file above is the entire of my htaccess file nothing with regards to AllowOverride None exists or the individual webspaces

Comment: Your `.htaccess` file should not look anything like what you posted above.  What you posted looks like an Apache server config file, which lives in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` and is linked to `/etc/apache2/sites-available` to enable that particular website.  A `.htaccess` file, however, lives in an *individual folder* in a website and specifies options related to *that folder* - *not* `VirtualHost` or logging directives.

Comment: yes sorry thats what i meant to say. Apologises i meant to say my apache conf file (as i posted above) doesn't seem to have any AllowOverride None or All any advise?

Comment: Please edit the question to reflect this - it still says that's your `.htaccess` file.  Please also post the `.htaccess` file you're trying to use.

Comment: I do realise that however upon putting my .htaccess into the /var/www/test/ the .htaccess file doesn't work but i imagined it was to do with the fact the /test/ file hasn't been configured in the apache config file

Comment: Please post the `.htaccess` file you're trying to use.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36484/discussion-between-jnylen-and-liam-sorsby)